# How do I prevent Gnus from changing the window layout?

Tags: gnus

When I open a group in Gnus, it insists on resetting the window layout and using the entire frame for the group buffer.

I'd rather manage the window layout myself, so how can I make Gnus not change it for me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the variable `gnus-use-full-window` to `nil`.  [The manual warns](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Window-Layout.html) against doing so:

> Setting this variable to `nil` kinda works, but there are glitches. Use at your own peril.

But I haven't seen anything I'd call "glitches" related to that.